# User Assignment in Azure App registration

Tags: wpf, azure, azure-active-directory, single-sign-on

So, I have a WPF application, and I wanted to integrate SSO to it.
I successfully made it with "App registration" under Azure.

But now I have a problem, the users under the Azure AD can successfully connect to the app, but I want to specify which users in my AD can access to this app.

I didn't find any way to do this, and I see that in "Enterprise application" we can do so.

I wanted to know if there is any way to do it with "App registration" or if I must switch to use "Enterprise Application" and if so how can I handle the authentication in my WPF app .

In my case I use this to authenticate in the wpf app with "Tenant" and "clientId" from the app registration:

```
PublicClientApp = PublicClientApplicationBuilder.Create(ClientId)
                .WithRedirectUri("https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/nativeclient")
                .WithAuthority(AzureCloudInstance.AzurePublic, Tenant)
                .Build();



authResult = await PublicClientApp.AcquireTokenInteractive(scopes)
                           .ExecuteAsync();
```

Comment: If anybody interested , this was solved by using MsGraph api and checking users in app.
I don't know if this is the best way to do it  but it worked for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "registered application" is just a notification to the AAD that this application uses AAD for authentication.  Once your user logs in, you can check that the user belongs to a security group that is allowed permission to use the application.  There may be a better way to do this, but I check in the application itself.

Comment: Hello,Thanks for responding, sorry i'm new to azure ad , how can we check if the user belongs to a security group in Azure AD ? thanks

Comment: This was solved by using MsGraph api and checking users in app.

Answer (score 1):

To grant access only for a specific subset of users/groups in Azure AD you should create "Enterprise Application" and assign necessary users/groups to it like in [this example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/add-application-portal-assign-users).

Also you will need to configure single sign-on (SSO) and ensure that app's "User assignment required" property is enabled. All the steps are described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/add-application-portal)

Comment: Yes I have seen the examples, but the problem with entreprise Application is how can i connect my users via the wpf application ?